# How to make an input variable that accepts both strings and ints?

Tags: python, input

I have a code that plots points in different colours depending on a value the user puts in but I want to make an if/else type statement that will plot the graph in one colour if the user does not know the values required. The code can be seen below:

```
test = []

start = 0
end = int(input("How many non primary sources do you have?\n(If you do not know this value please enter x:)")) - 1

if end == x:
    end == len(test)
    start2 = 0
    end2 = len(test)
    plt.scatter(Alpha[start:end], Beta[start:end], color=['green'])
    plt.scatter(Alpha[start2:end2], Beta[start2:end2], color=['red'])
    plt.show()
else:
    start2 = end + 1
    end2= len(test) - 1
    plt.scatter(Alpha[start:end], Beta[start:end], color=['green'], marker = '+', label = 'Non primary source')
    plt.scatter(Alpha[start2:end2], Beta[start2:end2], color=['red'], marker = '*', label = 'Primary source')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

There was a lot of code before this which I cut out as it shouldn't been needed but again is there a way for there to be a user input that allow for both numbers and strings to be taken such that if they do not know how many primary sources they have they can type 'x' and have the code not crash?

Comment: don't set `end` to an int in the 3rd line.  your `if` statement should check `if end =="x"`, and in your `else` statement, add a line at the top `end = int(end)`

Answer (score 1):

Have them enter 0 or maybe -1 to indicate the unknown value.
Or you take the input as string and check if its x first and if its not, you try and cast it to int.

```python
end = input("How many non primary sources do you have?\n(If you do not know this value please enter x:)")
if end =="x":
    #plot with one color
else:
    try:
        end_int=int(end)
        #plot with more colors
    except ValueError:
        #catch input that is neither x nor an int
```